# Twitter Bootstrap: Positioning a button to the right of a block-level input box?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an input box and a button defined like so:

```
    <form class="form-inline">
        <input type="text" title= "language" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Insert Languages"/>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Filter by Languages</button>
    </form>
```

But the button shows up on the second line.  Is it possible to position the button to the right of the input box?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may be misunderstanding the use of `input-block-level` class.  When this class is applied to an input field, the input field will take *all* available width.

As a result, any element that you place next to it, will roll over to the next line.

If you need the elements to be side by side, remove `input-block-level` and replace with a more appropriate class (`input-mini`, `input-small`, `input-medium`, `input-large`, `input-xlarge`, `input-xxlarge` or `span` classes).

Comment: I'm using input-xxlarge, but it's still not big enough.  How do I customize it?  I've tried something like `.input-xxlarge {
   width: 1500px; !important;
   height: 30px !important;
  }` , but it doesn't override it.

Comment: Avoid customising the class if possible, you are using a frame work, use the built in classes and layouts.  The various `input` classes are set for some standard sizes.  If you need it bigger use the `span` classes like `span9` or `span12`.  See the section on control sizing at - http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using input-xxlarge, but it's still not big enough. How do I
>   customize it? I've tried something like .input-xxlarge { width:
>   1500px; !important; height: 30px !important; } , but it doesn't
>   override it. – Parseltongue 13 mins ago

Inspect the element with developer tools (like in Chrome, Safari etc) and see if other widths/heights are overriding your explicit declarations. I tried changing it on my end and was successful when I changed the actual class in bootstrap.css

Comment: Thanks-- I appreciate you taking the time to answer that.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to prevent the twitter boostrap button from reloading the page when you click it?  I just need it to call a function

Answer (score 0):

set widths desired to each element and float them:

```css
form{overflow: hidden}
form input{
    display: block;
    width: 70%;
    float: left;
}
form button{
    display: block;
    width: 30%;
    float: left;
}
```